# Laravel - 'and # more errors' - cambiar idioma

Tags: php, html, laravel

"cambie" el idioma de laravel (con laravel lang) para que los mensajes se muestren en español, el problema es que lo único que no cambia es el mensaje que se muestra cuando hay mas de 1 error.

Esos 'and 5 more errors' deberian estar en esp.
[image: Esos 'and 5 more errors' deberian estar en es.]

Supuestamente laravel lang tiene traducido todo el idioma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienen alguna idea de donde se cambia ? No encontré nada relacionado. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

En tu proyecto hay una sección para los lenguajes que puede utilizar tu aplicación, está en `resources > lang` y ahí verás los lenguajes que tienes hasta el momento

Si instalaste alguna otra cosa en tu proyecto como livewire o algo por el estilo que traiga sus propios archivos de lenguaje entonces tal vez laravel lang no los haya encontrado o no los tome en cuenta

Podrías ir manualmente a `resources > lang > en` y revisar cada uno de los archivos, el problema es que no vas a encontrar tal cual el texto "(and 5 more errors)" porque seguramente el número 5 es una variable y posiblemente "errors" también, porque podría ser "warnings", podría venir en algún archivo como:

```
(and :max more :attribute)
```

Otra opción es que el error venga directo de la validación en algún componente "blade" o "livewire". En tu primera foto veo algo que podría ser un formulario por lo que esta opción podría ser tu solución

En este caso, dentro de tu componente puedes definir tus reglas (Supongo que esto ya lo has hecho) de la siguiente forma (Por ejemplo para una variable `field` que tenga `id` y `name`)

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'field.id' => 'required',
        'field.name' => 'required|min:5',
    ];
}
```

En el mismo componente puedes sobre escribir los mensajes de validación de la siguiente forma:

```
protected $messages = [
    'field.id.required' => 'Este campo no puede estar vacío.',
    'field.name.required' => 'Este campo no puede estar vacío.',
    'field.name.min' => 'El nombre debe tener por lo menos 5 caracteres.',
];
```